# How do we obtain Pokestop modules?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the Pokestop screen, there is an 'empty module' that can be upgraded - how do I actually find one?

Comment: I assume you mean Pokestops?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of version 0.29.0, players may buy PokeStop Modules from the Store using PokeCoins. In future revisions, some Modules may be acquired from Pokestops, but that is not the case yet.

The following modules exist in the game as of the latest revision:

- **Lure Module** -- 100 Pokecoins
  This module allows a PokeStop to act like an Incensed player. However, it will increase the spawnrates for every player in the entire game. It also appears to be slightly more effective than Incense, at the cost of being more expensive.

Comment: You also acquire them as specific level-up bonuses.

Answer (score 2):

As of today i have acquired a lure module from a pokestop. I have tested this theory with 5 other local players and they too have gotten ONE from them. i'm not sure if its a RNG or if at a certain point you get them. but you can get free ones at some point.

Comment: What level are you on?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get one as a level up bonus? I received 2 by level 15.

Answer (score -3):

Listen. These people never got your question

You are clicking the module like I did!! That is incorrect. The module is where you put a "lure module" to attract Pokemon for all trainers in the area.

To get items you spin the circle - the thing that shows a pic of the building/location - until items pop out. Then you just pick up the items.
Just spin dear!

Comment: -1 | You did not answer the question. He asked "Where to get modules" not "Where to get items (in general)". This answer does not add anything new either.

Comment: however, i searched for this answer...