# What is a Pokestop Module?

Tags: pokemon-go

In a pokestop, I pressed a button and 
this menu appeared:-

[image]

So what is this pokestop module and what does it help in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do we obtain Pokestop modules?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272664/how-do-we-obtain-pokestop-modules)

Comment: Does your phone no support taking screen shots?

Comment: @gre_gor My phone's ram is only 1 GB. The game and phone lags too much. The phone also becomes very hot. So it is very difficult to take a screenshot.

Comment: Also I can't play Pokemon GO in my other phone which has 4GB RAM because it has intel core and the game does not support phones with intel core.

Comment: I don't know if that's a duplicate. The other one asks how to find them, this one asks what they are. Those are different questions.

Comment: Nice Spiderman-Design!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the main menu shop, you can purchase a Lure Module to be used at Pokestops. These attract wild Pokemon not only for you, but for other people as well.

[image]

Comment: They also attract other pokemon go players.

Comment: You can also start getting them from Pokestops when you hit level 8

Comment: @Taegost I'm level 15 and I haven't gotten a single one yet, despite sitting right next to two pokestops at my workplace and spinning them all day :(

Comment: I've only gotten 1 myself, although I was thinking about it afterwards, I think I leveled at around that same time, but it didn't actually tell me I leveled until at least 15 minutes later, so I'm wondering if it mixed up the rewards from the stop with the rewards from leveling