# How do I use a Lure Module?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 2 lure modules, and I would like to use one at the Pokéstop I am at, but when I tap on it, it says that it cannot be used here. How do I activate the lure module?

Comment: related http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272811/what-is-a-pokestop-module?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to a pokestop.
2. Activate the pokestop.
3. Touch the white space above the spinning circle (the shape of the lure module).
4. Confirm to use the lure module.
5. Wait around for half an hour and catch lots of pokemon.

Happy huntung!

If you need a source go to [https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rst52/cant_use_lure_module/](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rst52/cant_use_lure_module/%20here), or trust experience.

Answer (score 2):

After spinning the circle a white blank spot should appear above the pokéstop, tap that to install your lure.

[**Source**](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4rst52/cant_use_lure_module/)